# Erro em um sql no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com dificuldade em uma sql no laravel onde faço um join, mas o erro acontece mesmo é no `where`, onde o `deleted_at` é igual à `null`, lembrando que o `deleted_at` é um `timestamp`. No banco está funcionando a sql, mas no laravel não. O que falta? estou usando o banco postgres.

Segue a imagem do erro:
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloca o código que você esta utilizando para podermos te ajudar mais, outra pergunta você utilizou a query manual para testar ?

Comment: Eduardo, poste o código do seu model e, caso tenha utilizado, as migrations da sua tabela.

Comment: opa galera vlw pela ajuda mais eu já resolvi o problema eu não sabia que existia uma função "whereNull()" para fazer isso mais obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Eduardo coloque como resposta é muito bom ter esses erros e como resolve-los.

Answer (score 3):

Null não é um valor, mas sim "valor desconhecido", e por isto não pode ser comparado com valores normais.

no lugar de

```
"tb_combo_produto"."deleted_at" = null
```

utilize

```
whereNull('deleted_at')
```

Comment: Postei como CW para abrir mão dos votos, pois a resposta não é minha, e sim baseada num comment do OP. Caso o OP prefira, poste como resposta própria, que removemos esta.